# How can I *only* get the number of bytes available on a disk in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, linux-disk-free

`df` does a great job for an overview. But what if I want to set a variable in a shell script to the number of bytes available on a disk?

Example:

```
$ df
Filesystem            1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda             1111111111  2222222  33333333  10% /
tmpfs                  44444444      555  66666666   1% /dev/shm
```

But I just want to return `33333333` (bytes available on `/`), not the whole `df` output.

Comment: ?? `df | grep /dev/sda | awk '{print $4}'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Portably:

```
df -P /dev/sda1 | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
```

The `-P` option ensures that `df` will print output in the expected format, and will in particular not break the line after the device name even if it's long. Passing the device name as an argument to `df` removes any danger from parsing, such as getting information for `/dev/sda10` when you're querying `/dev/sda1`. `df -P` just prints two lines, the header line (which you ignore) and the one data line where you print the desired column.

There is a risk that `df` will display a device name containing spaces, for example if the volume is mounted by name and the name contain spaces, or for an NFS volume whose remote mount point contains spaces. In this case, there's no fully portable way to parse the output of `df`. If you're confident that `df` will display the exact device name you pass to it (this isn't always the case), you can strip it:

```
df -P -- "$device" | awk -vn=${#device} 'NR==2 {$0 = substr($0, n+1); print $3}'
```

Comment: On my macbook pro, this worked for me to just give me the human readable version of what is available: `df -h | grep disk1s5 | awk '{print $4}'`

Answer (score 14):

You may get exact number of bytes with df:

`df -B1 /
Filesystem            1B-blocks        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root 32893632512 13080072192 18119061504  42% /`

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want the actual number of bytes (as I did) and not the number of 1024-sized blocks. Of course, you still have to parse it with awk or whatever, but that's trivial. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You may use awk,

```
df | awk '$1=="/dev/sda"{print $4}'
```

Comment: Yeah i like yours more than mine. :D

Answer (score 4):

**Only in Linux**

```
df --output=avail
```

Comment: Im guessing this is linux only huh? My little mac doesnt have that option.

Comment: Mmm, I think you're right, this command works fine on Linux, but checking the mac df version it does not have the "--output" option...

Answer (score 3):

You can use an awk

```
df | grep sda | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: awk can do the pattern match too, so you could get rid of the grep

Comment: I could, but the OP may deem this an easier to understand and remember solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can query disk status with `stat` as well. To query free blocks on filesystem mounted at `/`:

```
stat -f -c '%f' /
```

To get the result in bytes instead of blocks, you can use shell's arithmetic:

```
echo $((`stat -f -c '%f*%S' /`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar answers to the ones shown, but if you don't know the name of filesystem and are just looking for the total available space on the partition.

```
df -P --total | grep 'total' | awk '{print $4}'
```