# echo command is not working as expected in shell scriptin

Tags: linux, shell, echo, linux-disk-free

I have my filesystem as like below

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol
                       20G  3.7G   15G  20% /
tmpfs                  71G  8.0K   71G   1% /dev/shm
```

And my code is as below:

```
varone = df -h | awk ' {print $1 }'
vartwo = df -h | awk ' NR == 2 {print $2","$3","$4","$5","$6 }'
echo "$varone $vartwo" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
```

I want to export the '`df -h`' into a csv file. Why I printed `$1` alone in one variable means, there is space in the '`df -h`' output. I want it to be printed in a **single line**.

When I run the script, it throws an error like

`varone: command not found`

`vartwo: command not found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable equal to the output from a command in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put spaces around the equal sign, and you need backquotes to put the result of your command in a variable.

Try this:

```
varone=`df -h | awk ' {print $1 }'`
vartwo=`df -h | awk ' NR == 2 {print $2","$3","$4","$5","$6 }'`
echo "$varone $vartwo" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
```

Comment: Consider to use `$()` instead of backtics.

Comment: That works @yoones. But it is not giving the output as expected. My expected output is to print 
/dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol 20G  3.7G   15G  20% /

in separate cells in a csv file

Comment: Then consider doing something like: `varone=\`df -h | awk ' {print $1 }' | tr '\n' ';'\``

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to capture df -h

```
varOne=`df -h -P| awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6 }'`
echo  "$varOne" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
```

Read about 'P' here

[How can I *only* get the number of bytes available on a disk in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249591/how-can-i-only-get-the-number-of-bytes-available-on-a-disk-in-bash)